# Word document converted to FlowDocument has strange internal structure

Tags: .net, vsto, flowdocument

I have a little Word addin that copies the current document or selection via the clipboard into a WPF `RichTextBox` for further processing. The code is then navigating through the resulting `FlowDocument`:

```
TextPointer cursor = document.ContentStart;
...
cursor = cursor.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
```

I'm only interested in cursors with `cursor.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text`. I would expect to get blocks that relate to whole paragraphs or at least uniformly formatted ranges in the source Word document. However, I've noticed that sometimes (and for my purposes too often to ignore it) the blocks start or end in the very middle of a word. Quite often (but not always) it is a position with a German umlaut, though by far not all umlauts produce such breaks.

Can someone explain what's happening here behind the scenes? Is there a better way to navigate through the document? Is there an easy way to recognize that two adjacent blocks  that I get this way (are they `TextRuns`?) cut a word in two halves and are not separated by, let's say, a paragraph?

I want to get maximum contiguous text blocks that ideally do not overlap paragraphs or formatting changes.